# JavaFX controller, after componenet injection event

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm looking for a way of registering to the FXML component injection on the controller.
so I would have method like so

void afterComponenetInjection();

That will be fired once FXML componenets are injected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such direct mechanism. However, all injection is guaranteed to be completed before the controller's `initialize()` method is called, so you could put such functionality in that method.

Alternatively, if you want this to be external to the controller itself, retrieve the controller from the `FXMLLoader`; once the `load()` method returns, injection will have been completed (and the `initialize()` method will be complete), so you can invoke any functionality you need after calling `load()`.

And I suppose a third option:
Define a BooleanProperty in the controller, and set it to true at the beginning of the `initialize()` method. Then register a listener with that property: again, since injection is complete before `initialize()` is called, your listener will be invoked when injection is complete. Something like:

```
public class MyController {
   @FXML
   private Node node1 ;
   @FXML
   private Node node2 ;

   private final ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper injected = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(this, "injected", false);

   public boolean isInjected() {
      return injected.get();
   }

   public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty injectedProperty() {
      return injected.getReadOnlyProperty();
   }

   public void initialize() { 
      injected.set(true);
      // other initialization...
   }
}

// elsewhere...
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(...));
MyController controller = new MyController();
loader.setController(controller);
controller.injectedProperty().addListener( /* will be invoked after injection....*/ );
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
```